# Is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803757/running-landscape-server-on-centos-rhel), asking how to install Landscape on CentOS/RHEL.

I think it's off-topic, as, even though Landscape is a product from Canonical, it's asking how to install it on a distribution we don't support. Others think it's fine, since Landscape is an Ubuntu service.

Since it has an on-topic element and something that's off-topic, I'm asking here. Is that question topical or not?

Comment: As Landscape is for managing Ubuntu Servers, it should be fine, no matter the host. We don't close v-box questions because the host is not Ubuntu and this seems the same situation. As Landscape is just for managing Ubuntu servers, then question will always, indirectly, be about Ubuntu. I vote it is on topic.